# How to test with Queues

Tags: unit-test

I wrote a trigger on a custom object, that should be able to handle an user and a queue as owner. In oder to test this i wrote a simple test:

```
Group testGroup = new Group(Name = 'Queue', Type = 'Queue');
insert testGroup;

QueueSobject testQueue = new QueueSObject(QueueId = testGroup.Id, SobjectType = 'Lead');
System.runAs(new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId())) {   
    insert testQueue;
}

Lead l = new Lead(OwnerId = testGroup.Id, LastName = 'test', Company = 'test');
insert l;
```

This works fine for a Lead, but when i tried to do the same with an Opportunity or a custom object and i got the following error:

```
INVALID_OPERATION, Queue not associated with this SObject type: []
```

I do not understand what is the difference between the lead and the other objects and i did not find examples other than for the lead.

Answer (score 2):

Queues do not work with Opportunities. For a full list of supported sObjects, check out the documentation at http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/queues_overview.htm.

In short, you can use queues with:

- Leads
- Cases
- Knowledge articles
- Service contracts
- Custom objects

Comment: Mike, thanks for pointing out that queues are not working with Opportunities. Do you have any Idea, why it would not work with a custom object either?

Comment: How is your custom object defined? You should be able to just assign the queue to the OwnerID, unless it's the child in a Master-Detail.

Comment: It is not in a Master-Detail-Relationship and i am able to make a queue the owner over the UI, but it is not working in the test.

Answer (score 0):

Since,

Queues are not supported for opportunity , why don't you use queues on leads as usual and have the lead converted to opportunity and it will have same owner as the lead owner. Hope this helps.

Thanks.